# joomla - can't find articles category on content table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have running joomla site. from admin panel I can see the the category id = 10 and i'm sure it has articles.

when I select this category from table jom_content, which should have the all articles in, i get nothing. when I change category id to 8, i can get content of cat 8.

The table jom_content has  >150.000 article.

Is there any other place that joomla can store this category articles in ?

**Edit:**
This category has sub categories and articles belongs to sub category. May be it's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

When category has parent category it should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM `jom_content` WHERE catid in (SELECT id FROM `jom_categories` WHERE parent_id =10)
```